# Creating a loop over variables' names

Tags: r, loops, dummy-variable

I'm new to R (started a few days ago) and coming from STATA. I am trying to create a loop to create dummy variables when a variable has value -9. I want to use a loop as I have got plenty of variables like this.

In the following, reflex_working is my dataframe and "A7LECTUR" etc are my variables. I am trying to create a dummy called "miss_varname" for each variable using the ifelse function.

```
varlist<-c("A7LECTUR", "A7GROASG", "A7RESPRJ", "A7WORPLC", "A7PRACTI", 
"A7THEORI", "A7TEACHR", "A7PROBAL", "A7WRIASG", "A7ORALPR")

for (i in varlist){
    reflex_working$miss_[i]<-ifelse(reflex_working$i==-9,1,0)
    }
```

I get the following warnings for each iteration:

```
1: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'miss_'.
2: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'i'.
```

And no variable is created. I assume this must be something very trivial for everyone, but I have been trying for the last hour to create this kind of loop and have zero results to show.

Edit:
I have something like:

```
A7LECTUR
1
2
1
4
-9
```

And would like, after the loop, to have a new column like:

```
reflex_working$miss_A7LECTUR
0
0
0
0
1
```

Hope this helps clarifying what I'm trying to achieve!
Any help would be seriously appreciated.

Gabriele

Comment: Could you post example data and the desired result for the example data? It is a bit hard to understand what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: Maybe you meant `reflex_working[[paste0("miss_", i)]]`? Do you want to have columns like "miss_A7LECTUR", is that what you want?

Comment: @January yes, that is exactly what I would like to get! Could you be so kind to give me an example code? Being very new to R, I have no idea how to use paste0("miss_", i). I am so sorry for being such a noob!

Comment: Just replace `reflex_working$miss_[i]` with @January's code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break this down into why it doesn't work. For starters, in R

```
i
A7LECTUR 
# and
"A7LECTUR"
```

are different. The first two are variable*names*, the latter is a *value*. I am emphasising this difference, because it is an important distinction.

Working with *lists* (and data frames, as data frames are basically lists with some restrictions to make them rectangular), in the syntax `reflex_working$i` `reflex_working` refers to the variable and `i` is refers to the element named "i" within the list. In `reflex_working$i`, the `i` is *literal* and R doesn't care if you have an variable named `i`.

With programming, we want to be a bit more dynamic. So you correctly assumed using a variable would do the trick. If you want to do that, you have to use the `[` or `[[` subset method (`[` *always* returns a list, while `[[` will return the element without the encapsulating list[1]).

To summarise:

```
reflex_working$i    # gets the element named i, no matter what.
reflex_working[[i]] # gets the element whose name (or position) is stored in the variable i
reflex_working$i == reflex_working[["i"]]
```

That should explain the right-hand-side of your line in the loop. The correct statement should read

```
ifelse(reflex_working[[i]]==-9,1,0)
```

For the left-hand-side, `reflex_working$miss_[i]`, things are completely off. What you want can be decomposed into several steps:

1. Compose a value by concatenating "miss_" and the value of `i`.
2. Use that value as the element/column name.

We can combine these two into (as a commentor stated)

```
reflex_working[[paste0('miss_', i)]] <- ...
```

Good job on you, for realising that R is inherently vectorized - since you are not writing a loop for each row in the column. Good one!

---

[1] but `[[` can return a list, if the element itself is a list. R can be... <strike>weird</strike> full of surprises.

Comment: Thank you so much @MrGumble that was exactly what I was looking for! Your explanation is amazing! :-)

Comment: What you call "variable*names*" are correctly called symbols.

Comment: I appreciate your comment, @Roland.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want this for the entire data frame.

```
tt <- read.table(text="
A7LECTUR A7GROASG
1        2
2        3
1        -9
4        -9
-9       0", header=TRUE)

tt.d <- (tt == -9)*1
colnames(tt.d) <- paste0("miss_", colnames(tt))
tt.d
#      miss_A7LECTUR miss_A7GROASG
# [1,]             0             0
# [2,]             0             0
# [3,]             0             1
# [4,]             0             1
# [5,]             1             0
```